# Need Basic component/circuit that if given the input volatage [-2,-1,0,1,2] will output, [-1,0,0,0,1]

Tags: voltage, components, ternary

as a hobby I'm working on a ternary computer, using very basic building block.
in order to implement an half adder, I need a very basic component/circuit, that take the following input voltage, [-2,-1,0,1,2] and outputs this voltage [-1,0,0,0,1].
 I don't want something that return -0.5 volts if given -1v, it has to be close to 0v.

does anyone know of any basic component that does this?

```
Input | output
==============
-2    |  -1
-1    |   0
0     |   0
1     |   0
2     |   1
```

Comment: Do you really need to build this, if yes how many? I mean, is it acceptable for this circuit to require three or four opamps?

Comment: sure its OK to use several opamps.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work? The comparators have an NPN open-collector output, with the emitter connected to the 'ground' indicated for the comparator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGMO9J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your's in basically the same as mine but simpler. I'll delete and +1

Comment: +1. Without power, speed, driving capabilities or any other spec that is the best you could probably get.